# How to create dynamic design in DotnetNuke based on field type?

Tags: c#, wcf, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I am working on a project where I have a 2 Module: 1- Account, 2- Order. I want to create dynamic design for it. I don't know how to explain properly. Let me give you example.

i.e If user click on `Add Account` button in Account Tab, I will get list of fields and types from `WCF service`. I want to design `Add Account` form on the base of field and its typs. If fields has `String` type, it should create a `Lable` and a `Textbox` to enter value. Sameway if type is `Radio`, it should create a `Lable` with `Radio` button.

Is there any easier way in DotnetNuke for such functionlity for Create, Display, Edit forms?

Is there is no such functionality, I must create design using code which is not good idea in terms of speed and performace.

Please guide me. All the suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Go shopping at the [DNN store](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-list?searchtext=form%20master&categorylist=111&sortby=reviewdesc&page=1). There you can just buy modules that can create forms. It is probably much easier and cheaper than building one yourself.

Comment: Thanks but it is not just limited to create forms. There is much more. It just start. Is there any inbuild/inherit functionality of DNN that can helpful in above scienario? If so, please suggest.